# Parsing this xsl or xml format

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt

I already asked a question about my code and some nice guys put me on the right way, but now I need to know something specific and hope you can help me.
I googled for hours and found some things, but cant really figure out if it is the correct solution. 
Ok, let me explain.
I have this code in my file:

> ```
> <states xsi:type="auto:InitialState" name="Anfang"/>
> <act name="Megadon" start="//@states.2" end="//@states.3"/>
> ```

I found a clue that this is not xml format, but xsl format.
First question: Is this correct?

My goal is to transform it in xml format like this:

> ```
> <states> <xsi:type>auto:InitialState</xsi:type> <name>Anfang</name> </states>
> <act> <name>Megadon</name> <start>//@states.2</start> <end>//@states.3</end> </act>
> ```

The **real** xml.
I got the suggestion to use a tool called XSLT.
Second question: Do I need to parse it somehow by myself, or can I simply give my xsl format as input and get a xml as output?
Somehow I find always find ways from xml to this xsl format, not the other way around.
My goal is to transform this xsl file in eclipse via java code to a xml file.
Third question: Can you give me a tip to do this, or a website with help?

Thank you!

Regards
Dotana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSL (which is the same as XSLT) *is* a form of XML, but the XML you have shown there isn't XSLT. You can use XSLT to convert that XML into the format you want, like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="act">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
        <xsl:sort 
          select="string-length(
                    substring-before('|name|start|end|',
                                     local-name()))"
          data-type="number" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="act/@*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you run this XSLT with the following as its input:

```
<n xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <states xsi:type="auto:InitialState" name="Anfang"/>
  <act name="Megadon" start="//@states.2" end="//@states.3"/>
</n>
```

The result will be:

```
<n xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <states xsi:type="auto:InitialState" name="Anfang" />
  <act><name>Megadon</name><start>//@states.2</start><end>//@states.3</end></act>
</n>
```